# Is there a debug log level for Salesforce Streaming?

Tags: streaming-api, debug-logs

Is there a debug log level for Salesforce Streaming ?

For example, let's say that, I have subscribed to PushTopic or Platform Events?
Is there a debug log level setting which allows to see the logs when that event was emitted by Salesforce ?

Answer (score 2):

While enabling logs you need to select Automated Process for getting logs from Platform Events.
[image]